# extracting attribute value of parent element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Experienced with Java, pretty new to Selenium, locators, etc.

Buried deep in some HTML is several similar divisions:

```
<div tabgroup="topTabs__County Summary" sectiongroup class="field TextDescription tab">
  <label for="request_48543">
    <span class="label">Monument</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div tabgroup="topTabs__County Summary" sectiongroup class="field DropDownList readonly tab">
  <label for="request_48543">
    <span class="label">Geolocation</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div tabgroup="topTabs__County Summary" sectiongroup class="field SingleLineText tab">
  <label for="request_48543">
    <span class="label">Intersection</span>
  </label>
</div
```

I need some Selenium magic to find a label with a specific value then backtrack to find that label's division and from that division extract the value of a given attribute. Drilling down seems fairly easy but how does one "back up" ?

For example, given "Geolocation" I'd like to extract "field DropDownList readonly tab"

I've tried things like

```
WebElement chill = m.findElement(By.xpath("../..//span[text='Geolocation']"));
```

to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reversed the order of going to the parent element, and you need `()` in `text`. The `xpath` should be

```
"//span[text()='Geolocation']/../.."
```

Another option is to look for an element that has a chilled with "Geolocation" text

```
"//div[.//span[text()='Geolocation']]"
```

this might give you more results, depends on the html structure that is not in the question. In that case you can add unique attribute, for example `tabgroup`

```
"//div[.//span[text()='Geolocation']][@tabgroup]"
```

this will return only `<div>` tag that has `tabgroup` attribute.

To extract the data use `getAttribute("class")` on `chill` `WebElement`

Comment: The first option did the trick, no muss no fuss, thanks!  SO rocks!